# How NFA decides how to break up a string?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

If we have a language K, that word w=uv, accepts.
$K= \{{w \in \{a, b ,c\}^*: \ \vert u \vert_a \  \text{is not divisible by 3}}\}$. Can we land strings like `aaaa` in final state? How does NFA decides to break up the string in this case, would it be `u = aa, v = aa` (w accepted) or `u = aaa, v = a` (w is not accepted). Or doesn't matter and we can land everything as long as right decomposition exists.

Comment: NFA is, as the name says, non-deterministic. There might be several paths for one input string. As long as the NFA is correct and the input string is an acceptable string, there exists a path to reach the final state.

Comment: I suggest looking up the definition of the language accepted by an NFA. The definition contains all the information you need.

Comment: I don't understand the definition of $K$. Do you require that $w$ has a prefix $u$ such that $|u|_a$ is not divisible by $3$? In this case, $K = \{a,b,c\}^*a\{a,b,c\}^*$